# conversion of mysql to msqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Mysql is deprecated. I have a code in mysql that I would like to convert to mysqli, but I don't succeed.

The code works, but I have error messages "The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead"

Here is the initial code:

```
$connection = mysql_connect('host','root','password') or die ("Couldn't connect to server.");  
$db = mysql_select_db('database_name', $connection) or die ("Couldn't select database.");  

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE cust_number ='$Cust_Number' ");

if( mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE `customers` SET cust_name='$Cust_Name', cust_phone='$Cust_Phone', cust_phone1='$Cust_Phone1', cust_email='$Cust_Email', cust_address='$Cust_Address' ");
}
else
{
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO customers (cust_number, cust_name, cust_phone, cust_phone1, cust_email, cust_address) VALUES ('$Cust_Number', '$Cust_Name', '$Cust_Phone', '$Cust_Phone1', '$Cust_Email', '$Cust_Address') ");
}
```

I tried the following conversion:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect('host','root','password') or die ("Couldn't connect to server.");  
$db = mysqli_select_db($connection,'database_name') or die ("Couldn't select database."); 

if( mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    mysqli_query($connections,"UPDATE `customers` SET cust_name='$Cust_Name', cust_phone='$Cust_Phone', cust_phone1='$Cust_Phone1', cust_email='$Cust_Email', cust_address='$Cust_Address' ");
}
else
{
    mysqli_query($connections,"INSERT INTO customers (cust_number, cust_name, cust_phone, cust_phone1, cust_email, cust_address) VALUES ('$Cust_Number', '$Cust_Name', '$Cust_Phone', '$Cust_Phone1', '$Cust_Email', '$Cust_Address') ");
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Can someone help me convert the initial code in mysqli or PDO?

Comment: You can try following:

Answer (score 0):

Your `mysqli_query()` calls `$connections`, whereas your connection is `$connection` -- this is why your code is failing.

It is, however, worth noting that as it stands, your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). To avoid this, you'll want to make use of [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) (something which didn't exist with the MySQL connector).

This can be done with the following:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect('host','root','password') or die ("Couldn't connect to server.");  
$db = mysqli_select_db($connection,'database_name') or die ("Couldn't select database."); 

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("UPDATE `customers` SET cust_name='?', cust_phone='?', cust_phone1='?', cust_email='?', cust_address='?'");
    $stmt->bind_param('sssss', $Cust_Name, $Cust_Phone, $Cust_Phone1, $Cust_Email, $Cust_Address);
    $stmt->execute();
}
else
{
    $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO customers (cust_number, cust_name, cust_phone, cust_phone1, cust_email, cust_address) VALUES ('?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?') ");
    $stmt->bind_param('ssssss', $Cust_Number, $Cust_Name, $Cust_Phone, $Cust_Phone1, $Cust_Email, $Cust_Address);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: How should I write the following part:                                                                         $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE cust_number ='$Cust_Number' ");